# Concat columns all but one column into a list in a new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have found several posts similar to this, but not one exactly.

I have a `df` like this:

```
0    1    2    3
abc  0    1    1
def  1    0    0
dfe  0    0    1
```

I am trying to make a new column with all the data but the first column into a list but drop the zeros, like this:

```
0    1    2    3   new_col
abc  0    1    1   [1,1]
def  1    0    0   [1]
dfe  0    0    1   [1]
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't drop the zeros and i can't figure out how to exclude the first column:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)

#thought this might work but it doesn't:
df[[1:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis = 1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your approach work, you do [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str)
                .agg(lambda x: ' '.join(i for i in x if i != '0'), axis=1)
                .str.split())

     0  1  2  3 new_col
0  abc  0  1  1  [1, 1]
1  def  1  0  0     [1]
2  dfe  0  0  1     [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not very elegant, but:
You can apply the following function using lambda to new_col:

```
def remove_zeros(list):
    for i in list(l):
        if i==0:
            l.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` + `stack` , then aggregate is another way:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.iloc[:,1:].replace(0,np.nan).stack().astype(int)
                   .groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

---

```
print(df)

     0  1  2  3 new_col
0  abc  0  1  1  [1, 1]
1  def  1  0  0     [1]
2  dfe  0  0  1     [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and `boolean masking` to filter `non zero` values inside a list comprehension:

```
df['new_col'] = [[*x[x != 0]] for x in df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()]
```

**Result:**

```
     0  1  2  3 new_col
0  abc  0  1  1  [1, 1]
1  def  1  0  0     [1]
2  dfe  0  0  1     [1]
```

---

**Timings:** (Tested on dataframe with shape `(30000, 4)`)

```
%%timeit -n10
_ = [[*x[x != 0]] for x in df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()]
109 ms ± 5.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%%timeit -n10
_ = (df.iloc[:,1:].replace(0,np.nan).stack().astype(int)
                   .groupby(level=0).agg(list))
1.8 s ± 95.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%%timeit -n10
_= (df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str)
                .agg(lambda x: ' '.join(i for i in x if i != '0'), axis=1)
                .str.split())
1.39 s ± 20.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```